# Asset filtered out , although it's been added to the pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have a folder `my_project/app/my_assets`. Here's my `config/initializers/assets.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "my_assets")
Dir.glob(Rails.root.join("app", "my_assets", "*")).each do |a|
  Rails.application.config.assets.paths << a
  Dir.glob(File.join(a, "*")).each do |b|
   puts "b: #{b}"
    Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << b
  end
end
```

And here's code I have in `application.html.erb`:

```
<script src="<%= asset_path('my_js1.js') %>"></script>
```

That file is added to the pipeline, but I keep having this error:

```
Asset filtered out and will not be served: add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( my_js1.js )` 
to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server
```

I've restarted the server, but no avail.

Comment: Have you added the line `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( my_js1.js )` to the file `config/initializers/assets.rb` and then restart the server as it tells you to in the error message?

Comment: @LukaKerr, reread my question.

Comment: what rails version?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that your `b` variable is an absolute path but `precompile` is looking for a relative path (relative to your assets path). I'll delete this if it doesn't work, but it's worth a try.

Try

```
relative_path = File.basename(b)
# or alternatively b.split("/")[-1]
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << relative_path
```